# Is it possible to C++ compiler inline method calls across DLLs?

Tags: .net, c++, compiler-construction, jit

Is it possible to  C++ compiler  inline method calls across DLLs? 
Is it possible for .NET JIT  ?

Comment: For C++: surely no. How can you inline something you don't possess?

Comment: @ruslik: You don't need the source code to "possess" the function. You merely need to know which part of the object file to inline, which can be stored in the file by the compiler.

Comment: @Jorgen: Either it's in DLL, so it can be updated independently of the rest of the code, either you explicitely inline it, so it's no more in DLL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a definite Yes for a .NET jitter.  It merely loads IL from a DLL, just-in-time code generation makes the fact that it came from a DLL disappear.  All code from any DLL goes into the same loader heap.  One consequence of this is that a DLL cannot be unloaded unless the entire AppDomain is unloaded.

A definite No for the C++ compiler, the exported functions are precompiled and located at a fixed address, an offset from the DLL base address.  An indirect jump through the IAT is required, although optimizations are possible.  But not inlining, that has to be done by the compiler.

Comment: It's possible for JIT. I don't know if .NET does that. .NET will cache the compiled machine code for EXEs and DLLs and that cache would be useless if it recompiled a customized version for each run.

Answer (score 1):

If you hadn't included the ".net" tag, then the answer would be **NO**. However, with the ".net" tag, the jitter should be able to at least *optimize*, if not *inline*, unless the DLL is a native code DLL that you P/Invoke against.

Answer (score 1):

A function defined completely in a C++ header file must be inlined by the compiler under normal circumstances, because there is no assigned compilation unit for the function. Of course, one could say the function does not even belong to the DLL, since you won't find an entry point there for the function, but IMHO that's only a nitpicker's point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [/GL (Whole Program Optimization)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) flag for the compiler.

This flag tells the linker to optimize across module boundaries, including function inlining.

Comment: Just a clarification: that /GL is not for cross-DLL calls where one is native.

Comment: Right. It just helps you in organazing the code. Without it you would have to put most functions in headers or in a single huge .cpp file (to benefit most of inlining).